# InAppBrowser prevent from closing when close button pressed

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

`InAppBrowser` has a toolbar with 'Close' button.

I want to display a confirmation dialogue preventing `InAppBrowser` from closing if user decides to.

I know I can attach an event to 'exit' but it seems to me that I would rather need an event like 'onExiting'.

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', function (event) { alert(event.type); });
```

Any help please?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way you can accomplish this is by modifying the inappbrowser plugin.

For example, for Android you could modify [this click handler](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java#L636) to present a dialog before closing.

You will have to make similar changes to the native code of each platform you use.

Comment: I figured out something else. It is possible to (on exit event):
- ask user if he wants to leave application
- if not, open `InnAppBrowser` again